# Emacs command line arguments

Tags: emacs

How to start emacs and run  `M-x man` followed by the manpage name from bash.

I want this to have an alias to `man` in bash, but I'm new to emacs and can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emacs --eval '(man "emacs")'
```

Good luck getting the quoting right in your alias.  :-)

Comment: thanks, got the alias working with `manu() { emacs --eval "(man \""$1"\")" }`.  Finally I have proportional fonts for reading man pages.